# Why Windows 10 Splash screen not working with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I have installed dual OS(***Windows 10*** along with ***Ubuntu 16.04***) in my system. Problem is when I boot system with Windows 10 OS, it display something like below image, not the splash screen or welcome message.

> NOTE: Same problem continues with Ubuntu 18.04

[image]

How can I resolve this issue in my system ?

Comment: Does it boot to Windows or not? If not, your problem is not a splash screen, that's just a symptom.

Comment: it boot with window 10, but when booting it shows above screen instead of Windows logo and welcome screen..

Comment: Probably an unintended side-effect of the dual boot. I assume both OSes are installed in UEFI mode?

Comment: yes, both are installed in UEFI mode..

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: you can like and Up-Vote this question so in future if somebody post a correct answer you will know it.

Comment: your drivers not supported

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I am using SSD) and here is what I did in BIOS:

1. Under Boot Sequence, I have Legacy option selected
2. Under Advanced Boot Options, I have checked Enable Legacy Option ROMs
3. Secure Boot is disabled
4. Fastboot is set to Minimal
5. I have my SATA operation set to RAID mode (this was already checked)

If the above points don't work, just try changing to UEFI mode and boot. If that doesn't work, try changing it back which worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

1) Open a terminal window. ...

2) cd /etc/grub.d

3) ls -l

4) Notice that there are approximately eight shell files with names that start with a number. These scripts get executed in numerical order.

5) sudo mv 30_os-prober 06_os-prober

This is going to move any non-Linux OS to the top of the list.

6) sudo update-grub

7) Restart Linux to test your work.